# How to find parents of e.target and their children. And move a 'active class'

Tags: javascript, dom-events

This code is about event of 'active' button. I have to use this code globally. But it conflicts with all the elements that have the `btn` class.

So I want to give an active class when I click on `btn` (button). And when I click on the `btn`, I want to find the parents of `e.target`, find their children, and move a 'active class'. And I want to use this code globally. But my code is not working. Because It can't find parents of `e.target` exactly. Is there any other good way?

```
var btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
  [].forEach.call(btns, function (item) {
    item.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      var selectedParent = e.target.parentNode;
      var selected = selectedParent.querySelectorAll('.btn.active');
      if (selected.length > 0) {
        selected[0].className = selected[0].className.replace(' active', '');
        item.className += ' active';
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `e.target.parentElement` instead of `e.target.parentNode`?

Comment: @secan: In most cases, it does not matter which property you use, however, parentNode is probably the most popular.

Comment: So you want the click on one button to remove the active class from all other buttons and add it to the clicked one?

Comment: @WaisKamal Yes! And one more condition, 'active class' should be transferred from same parent's children.

Comment: Are all the buttons nested under the same parent? If you can provide a sample of your HTML it would be easier to understand how your buttons are nested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your buttons are all under the same parent element, then you can do it this way (I have included an `.active` class just to show the effect):

```js
var btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
[].forEach.call(btns, function(item) {
  item.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var selectedParent = e.target.parentNode;
    var childBtns = selectedParent.children;
    for(var i = 0; i < childBtns.length; i++) {
      childBtns[i].classList.remove("active");
      this.classList.add("active");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  background: #F55;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Button 1</button>
<button class="btn">Button 2</button>
<button class="btn">Button 3</button>
<button class="btn">Button 4</button>
<button class="btn">Button 5</button>
```

**Edit:** actually this works even if the buttons are not under the same parent.

Answer (score 0):

Probably replace e.target to e.currentTarget OR item.parentNode will also do.

Comment: I did what you wrote. But results was ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null```.